# Are DOM circular references found by chrome,firefox and IE?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, circular-reference

I was reading about DOM circular references and how they were a cause for memory leak in javascript especially in IE 6 and 7.Do the modern browsers use mark-and-sweep technique to effectively remove these objects from memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are DOM circular references found by chrome,firefox and IE?

Yes (well, recent IE, I think you're safe from IE9 onward).

I can't speak to the exact mechanism they use and wouldn't be at all surprised if they used different ones, but they all release circularly-referenced structures if nothing links them back to the root.

The problem with older IE wasn't circular references in the DOM itself (which it handled), it was circular references between JavaScript objects (including behind-the-scenes objects used by closures) and DOM objects. But IE8 improved things markedly, and I believe IE9 dealt with the last of it.